# Find anchor (has other html elements) with specific text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find the list item based on the contents in the anchor.

I tried using the following xpath

```
//li/a[contains(., 'India')]
```

It is working for unique items, But here, it is matching more than one item.

I want to ignore the the other contents in anchor and only focus on the anchor text to identify the li. How can i achieve it?

```
<ul>
   <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#"><img src="1" class="flag">&nbsp;Afghanistan</a></li>
   <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#"><img src="2" class="flag">&nbsp;India</a></li>
   <li style="display: list-item;"><a href="#"><img src="3" class="flag">&nbsp;British Indian Ocean Territory</a></li>
</ul>
```

PS: Tried the following, it works. But later if the position of "&nbsp ;" changes, it's going to fail.

```
//li/a[ends-with(normalize-space(.),'India')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `normalize-space()` was a good idea but it [would not handle `&nbsp;` by definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35676242/771848). You can do two things:

- translate a non-breaking space entity into a regular space
- compare the full string value of a node with a desired string

Final XPath:

```
//li/a[normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')) = 'India']
```